# Passing query id in api request send undefined id while refrshing page

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, next.js, mern

> In nextJs,I am making blog web apps. I want to get value of particular blog passing an id in api request.

```
const ViewDetail = () => {
  const[categoriesData,setCategoriesData]=useState([]);
  const router=useRouter();
  

  const fetchCategoreis=async()=>{
   
      const res=await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/blogs/${router.query.id}`)
      const data=await res.json();
      setCategoriesData(data.dataById)
    }

    
   
    useEffect(()=>{
      fetchCategoreis();
  },[])

  return (
    <>
<Box>
  <Image src={`/uploads/${categoriesData.pic}`}/>
  <Title>{categoriesData.title}</Title>
  <Author>Author:<span> </span><p style={{fontWeight:600,display:"inline-block"}}>{categoriesData.username}</p></Author>
  <Typography>{categoriesData.description}</Typography>
</Box>
    </>
  )
}
```

While I refresh page I get undefined value of req.params.id on server side(node js)

```
const getByIDBlogController=async(req,res)=>{
  console.log(req.params.id)
}
```

**output on server 
req.params.id value 64903e9170559406037885ed 
req.params.id value undefined 
req.params.id value undefined 
**

I want to get only id of particular blog but am getting undefined  of params(id) when page is refreshed.How do I slove this problem.

Comment: add router?.query?.id as useEffect dependency

Answer (score 1):

Update This Code With Some Condition

```
useEffect(()=>{
      fetchCategoreis();
  },[])
```

// Updated Code

```
useEffect(()=>{
     if( router?.query?.id !== 'undefined' && categoriesData === [] ) {
        fetchCategoreis();
     }
},[]) // Add Rest Dependency Here
```

It Is Most Easy Way To Resolve This Error

And There Is So Many Way But it Is Easiest/Laziest one

Comment: It does  not work. The main issue is I am getting undefined value of 'req.params.id' after I refresh same  page.

Comment: Sorry Now I have Fixed This Error You Can Simply Do By Written **`router?.query?.id`**